# How to connect to Bigtable running inside VPC using Java client libraries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am trying to understand how to connect to Bigtable running in virtual private cloud.

I am using Java client library code to connect to Bigtable. But it connects to service address (bigtable.googleapis.com) by default. However I need to connect to different service address: bigtable-xyz.googleapis.com

BigtableDataSettings settings =
BigtableDataSettings.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).setInstanceId(instanceId).build();

BigtableDataClient dataClient = BigtableDataClient.create(settings);

I don’t see a way to pass host name or connection url.

Does anyone know the solution

Thanks

Checked different ways of creating Bigtable connection

Comment: I recommend including the version of the SDK you are using and a link to the API documentation that you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the endpoint:

```
BigtableDataSettings.Builder settings = BigtableDataSettings.newBuilder()
                .setProjectId("project-id")
                .setInstanceId("instance-id");

settings.stubSettings().setEndpoint("bigtable-xyz.googleapis.com:443");
        
BigtableDataClient client = BigtableDataClient.create(settings.build());
```